Using OAuth2 for Azure DevOps API with an Application Registration
So, I am trying to use the Azure DevOps REST API with an application registration in Entra to authenticate. Azure DevOps is connected to my tenant, and the application is added as an User that's been given permissions. I'd like for my personal account to be able to authenticate impersonating as the Application, but i would also like to move this into perhaps an Azure Function or whatever down the road.
What's 'this'? 'This' is going to be either my Powershell that is going to create and configure new projects. Perhaps even add users to specific projects so I won't have to. Anything the Azure DevOps REST API supports which I am required to do manually on a daily/weekly base.
I did read the docs about the OAuth2 flow, but none of that makes any sense to me. The steps aren't clear enough. Callback URLs, Redirect URIs?
And then still, it wouldn't be enough for me to know how to use that flow from Powershell.
I also checked in the OAuth2 configuration of my organization on Azure DevOps, but it requires me to choose Bitbucket Cloud, Github or Github Enterprise? I'm not sure why it could only be those three platforms for OAuth2, but my guess is this is not the config I'm looking for.
If anyone could enlighten me to a higher level, and help me out, that would be very appreciated.

You cannot impersonate unless you are an Admin.   You have a two port application where port 1 is a client/server connection and port 2 is a server/database connection.  Bitbucket Cloud, Github or Github Enterprise is the backend connection (port 2).  OAUTH2 is being used on the frontend connection (port 1)

I am an admin in Entra, and I am an admin in Azure Devops. So why can't Azure DevOps be the backend itself? It's the place I am storing the code, where the pipelines run, where releases are done. It seems weird to me I would use something else as backend when I've already got Azure DevOps. I've seen plenty of applications with users/groups configured on the enterprise applications, with admin consent granted, where people who are not admins can logon impersonating as the Application. So Entra, or not being an admin cannot be a reason is what i'm thinking. Or is that too simple thinking?

You did not say in you posting that you were an admin.  You also said you were using azure.  Azure is a web application which is a server.  So to connect to the server you need a web client.  The webclient is the frontend which can be a local (a virtual connection) or remote.  When virtual the same app can start both server then client. If you are login using an app an admin must grant permission to the app before uses can run the app in admin mode.  The granting is done only once.

You can use the following PowerShell script to get the token of the application
$tenantId = "your-tenant-id"
$clientId = "your-client-id"
$clientSecret = "your-client-secret"
$resource = "499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798" #(the Azure DevOps resource's UUID is 499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798) 

$body = @{
    grant_type    = "client_credentials"
    client_id     = $clientId
    client_secret = $clientSecret
    resource      = $resource
}

# Get the token
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"  -Body $body
$token = $response.access_token

# Display the token
$token

Then you can call an Azure DevOps API by passing it in the headers as a Bearer token. For example: Authorization = "Bearer $token".
You can also refer this Q&A to get the token with Azure CLI command az account get-access-token.

Thanks, at least this way I can use the client ID/secret to perform actions against the API.

Hi @Marco, thanks for your response. If you have more question about the issue or the above PowerShell script don't work for you, please just let me know. Happy coding!
